Using top level bindings in modules in a program that uses C and Guile cooperation
I have a .c program which starts a Guile repl.
It then defines some wrappers using the
scm_c_define_gsubr 

function.
Then it loads an init .scm file.
In this .scm file I load some modules.
These modules cannot see the wrappers I have defined in the C file, but they are visible in the init .scm file.
How do I make the wrapped C functions visible in all modules?
I tried defining a module in the init file and exporting the wrapped functions and then
using
use-modules

inside the supporting modules to load the wrappers there. This gave me errors, so I assume that
this is not the way it is supposed to be done.
